# Disable Discount Coupon on Products with Promotional Price

Tags: opencart

Personal is there any way of not letting a discount coupon be used on products that already have a promotional price since I needed to create a discount coupon where it will give a 20% discount on my entire site but it can not be used on products that have one promotional discount on my site can someone help me please

Here are the options I currently have in my coupon:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

This is a product with a promotional price:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Is there a free module or some solution via source code or directly in the database?

Comment: What is your OpenCart version?

Answer (score 0):

In catalog/model/total/coupon.php

before the line with 'if ($status) {' add this code

```
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
        $product_special_query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_special_category` WHERE `product_id` = '" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "'");

        if ($product_special_query->row['total']) {
            $status = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

try it, the file path may change based on the version you're using.